# Чтение определённой строки из файла в переменной

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram, бот

Вообщем, делаю тг бота т.к. хорошая практика для новичка, не знаю как сделать переменную в которой будет читаться строка из файла. А если быть точнее нужно 2 переменных:

1. money, чтение 1 строки файла path.
2. lvl, чтение второй строки файла path.
   p.s.: нужно ещё сделать так чтобы во время чтения осуществлялась конвертация в int. Буду очень благодарен если кто-то поможет

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: `int[] numbers = File.ReadAllLines(path).Select(int.Parse).ToArray(); int money = numbers[0]; int lvl = numbers[1];`

Answer (score 0):

Вам до ботов ещё ооочень рано, если вы не можете даже считать информацию из файла, у вас даже базы нет, куда уже к практике лезть...

По вашему вопросу, вот вам [запись в файл](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/5.5.php), вот вам [чтение из файла](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/5.5.php). Когда будете считывать информацию из файла, не забудьте использовать цикл через [EndOfStreem](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.endofstream?view=net-7.0), это в разы упростит вам работу и часы поиска в интернете

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать структуру:

```
[Serializable]
public struct MyData{
  public int Money;
  public int Level;
}
```

Далее воспользоваться сериализацией в [JSON](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/6.5.php) или [XML](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/6.4.php)

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
 
// объект для сериализации
var data = new MyData(){
  Money = 100;
  Level = 1;
};
 
// передаем в конструктор тип класса Person
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyData));
 
// получаем поток, куда будем записывать сериализованный объект
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("dataFile.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(fs, data);
 
    Console.WriteLine("Object has been serialized");
}
```